# Подсветка в ScintillaNET

Tags: c#, .net, scintilla

До этого пользовался более старой версией. У меня есть код для включения подсветки в редакторе, но он не работает:

```
editor.Lexer = Lexer.PhpScript;
editor.LexerLanguage = "cpp";
```

И ещё... 
Как загрузить подсветку синтаксиса из файла XML?

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что новый ScintillaNET требует установки ForeColor для стилей.

```
editor.Styles[enum].ForeColor = color;
```